# IoC/DI - Implementation in internal class having only internal methods

Tags: ioc-container, ninject

We are implementing IoC/DI in our application using NInject framework. We are having internal classes having internal methods. To implement IoC/DI, we have to extract interfaces. But if we are having only internal methods in an internal class, we can't extract interface for that class.

So is there a way to implement IoC/DI in such cases (internal class having only internal methods) or should we change our internal methods to public methods. Kindly suggest. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing that you really need to make public is the interface (not the concrete implementation).

You can use an abstract factory or (easier) Ninject to map the public interface to the internal concrete; thus your client code just has to request an instance of "a thing" that implements the interface and your factory / container will return the implementation.

You should read up on Dependency Inversion Principle as well as it goes hand-in-hand with this.

Answer (score 3):

If your class is already internal then there is absolutely not difference between internal and public methods. public methods of internal classes are only internally visible.

If you stay with injecting concrete classes though you loose all the advantages of DI. So yes you should extract (internal) interfaces and inject the interfaces. This requires that the configuration code has access to the classes by either beeing in the same assembly of the assembly must be declased as friend assembly. Futhermore, you have to configure Ninject to allow none public classes. See NinjectSettings.

Answer (score 0):

You could use InternalsVisibleTo attribute in AssemblyInfo.cs file like this

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Assembly_That_Should_Access_The_Internal_Class")]
```